# Errors when attempting to configure a simple ActiveMQ Artemis cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, activemq-artemis

I'm in the process of coming up with a simple PoC ActiveMQ Artemis cluster configuration.

It's been pretty good so far getting individual brokers working, but I'm now at the point where I want to have one receive messages (`regional`) from producers and have those messages handled by consumers connected to the other node (`global`).

Unfortunately, when I start my `regional` broker, I end up seeing the following in its logs:

```
2020-06-12 14:06:59,005 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222186: unable to authorise cluster control
```

Looking over at the `global` broker at the same time, it's logging the following:

```
2020-06-12 14:08:00,524 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.ClusterController$ClusterControllerChannelHandler.handlePacket(ClusterController.java:364) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.handlePacket(ChannelImpl.java:720) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.doBufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:408) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:385) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:667) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.handlerRemoved(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:253) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:505) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:437) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ProtocolHandler$ProtocolDecoder.channelRead(ProtocolHandler.java:142) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]

2020-06-12 14:08:00,525 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222218: Server disconnecting: Error decoding buffer: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:390) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:667) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.handlerRemoved(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:253) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:505) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:437) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ProtocolHandler$ProtocolDecoder.channelRead(ProtocolHandler.java:142) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.ClusterController$ClusterControllerChannelHandler.handlePacket(ClusterController.java:364) [artemis-server-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.handlePacket(ChannelImpl.java:720) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.doBufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:408) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:385) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    ... 28 more

2020-06-12 14:08:00,528 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to /172.31.0.5:52646 has been detected: java.lang.NullPointerException [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
```

---

It's likely that I've missed something, but I have gone over the documentation several times and while it's overall good, I don't feel as though it's complete in describing the bare minimum for a working cluster configuration.

`global` `broker.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

        <name>0.0.0.0</name>

        <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

        <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
            ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
            MAPPED: mmap files
            NIO: Plain Java Files
        -->
        <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

        <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
        <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
        <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
        <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

        <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
        <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
        <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
        <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
        <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

        <!--
        This value was determined through a calculation.
        Your system could perform 50 writes per millisecond
        on the current journal configuration.
        That translates as a sync write every 20000 nanoseconds.
        Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
                We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
        -->
        <journal-buffer-timeout>20000</journal-buffer-timeout>

        <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
        -->
        <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
        <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
            <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

        <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
            <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

        <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
        <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

        <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
            it should accept IPV6
            Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
        <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

        <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
        <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

        <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
        <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->

        <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
        <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

        <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
            that won't support flow control. -->
        <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

        <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
        <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
        <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
        <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
        <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>

        <page-sync-timeout>1020000</page-sync-timeout>

        <acceptors>
            <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
            <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

            <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
            <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
        </acceptors>

        <cluster-user>cluster</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>REDACTED</cluster-password>

        <addresses>
            <address name="/queue/global.regional">
                <multicast>
                    <queue name="/queue/global.regional">
                        <durable>true</durable>
                    </queue>
                </multicast>
            </address>
        </addresses>

        <address-settings>
            <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
            <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
            </address-setting>

            <!--default for catch all-->
            <address-setting match="#">
                <!-- <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay> -->
                <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                <!-- <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
                <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics> -->
            </address-setting>
        </address-settings>

        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
            </security-setting>
        </security-settings>

    </core>
</configuration>
```

`regional` `broker.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

        <name>0.0.0.0</name>

        <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

        <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
            ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
            MAPPED: mmap files
            NIO: Plain Java Files
        -->
        <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

        <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
        <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
        <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
        <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

        <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
        <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
        <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
        <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
        <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

        <!--
        This value was determined through a calculation.
        Your system could perform 50 writes per millisecond
        on the current journal configuration.
        That translates as a sync write every 20000 nanoseconds.
        Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
                We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
        -->
        <journal-buffer-timeout>20000</journal-buffer-timeout>

        <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
        -->
        <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
        <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
            <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

        <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
            <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

        <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
        <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

        <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
            it should accept IPV6
            Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
        <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

        <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
        <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

        <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
        <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->
        <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
        <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
        <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
            that won't support flow control. -->
        <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
        <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
        <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
        <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
        <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
        <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
        <page-sync-timeout>1020000</page-sync-timeout>

        <acceptors>
            <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
        </acceptors>

        <connectors>
            <connector name="global">tcp://172.17.0.1:61616</connector>
        </connectors>

        <cluster-user>cluster</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>REDACTED</cluster-password>

        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="global">
                <address>/queue/global.regional</address>
                <connector-ref>global</connector-ref>
                <forward-when-no-consumers>false</forward-when-no-consumers>
                <static-connectors allow-direct-connections-only="true">
                    <connector-ref>global</connector-ref>
                </static-connectors>
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>

        <addresses>

        </addresses>

        <address-settings>

            <address-setting match="/queue/global.regional">
                <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
            </address-setting>

            <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
            <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
                <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
            </address-setting>

            <!--default for catch all-->
            <address-setting match="#">
                <!-- <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay> -->
                <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                <!-- <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
                <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics> -->
            </address-setting>
        </address-settings>

        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
            </security-setting>
        </security-settings>
    </core>
</configuration>
```

Would love to know why I'm getting these errors and what's preventing my clustering setup from getting off the ground.

---

References

- [ActiveMQ Artemis Bug Ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARTEMIS/issues/ARTEMIS-2803)

Comment: Do messages need to flow back and forth between the two brokers or do you just need to forward them from the `regional` broker to the `global` broker? If you need the former then a cluster would probably be the best fit, but if you need the latter then a simple core bridge would probably be best.

Comment: There will be some RPC/synchronous style interactions coming up. But yeah, what I have created so far is unidirectional. I'd ideally like to ensure that I don't close any doors or end up having to do deep reconfigurations in the future.

Comment: Based on your answer it's not clear to me if you want a full cluster or just a bridge.

Comment: I believe I want a full cluster to support configurations where messages can flow from global to regional (there will be several regional brokers as well, not just one).  Really, it might be best if I could just figure out my current error and then be free to compare the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing you need to configure a cluster is a `cluster-connection`. The `cluster-connection` will also need to reference a `connector` which specifies how *other* nodes can connect to it. In other words the `connector-ref` configured on the `cluster-connection` should match an `acceptor` configured on the broker.

If your `cluster-connection` is using *dynamic* discovery then you'll need a `discovery-group` and a `broadcast-group` and then reference the `discovery-group` in your `cluster-connection`. Since you're not using dynamic discovery I won't comment further on this.

If your `cluster-connection` is using *static* discovery then you'll need to define `connector` elements for the other nodes in the cluster and then reference those in your `cluster-connection` in the `static-connectors` section.

**Every** node in the cluster needs a valid `cluster-connection` configuration. This is the first error in your configuration. Your `global` broker doesn't define a `cluster-connection`. That's why you're seeing the `AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet: java.lang.NullPointerException` error on the `global` broker and the `AMQ222186: unable to authorise cluster control` error on the `regional` broker.

Also, **every** node in the cluster will need an `acceptor` which supports the `CORE` protocol because cluster connections use this protocol exclusively. This is the second error in your configuration. Your `regional` broker only has an `acceptor` which supports `STOMP`.

Other configuration issues (or potential issues):

1. The `connector-ref` of the `cluster-connection` on the `regional` broker (i.e. not the one in the `static-connectors`) is `global` which ostensibly points to the `global` broker. This is incorrect. It should be a connector which points to the `regional` broker. See the first paragraph of my answer for details about why.
2. The `address` of the `cluster-connection` on the `regional` broker references an address which isn't actually defined. It's typically best to define all your addresses and queues in `broker.xml` when using a clustered configuration.
3. The `forward-when-no-consumers` element of `cluster-connection` is deprecated. You should use `message-load-balancing` instead and select `OFF`, `STRICT`, or `ON_DEMAND` (default).
4. Ensure every node in the cluster uses the same `cluster-username` and `cluster-password`. Since your configurations have a redacted `cluster-password` it's impossible to tell if they're using the same value or not.

For what it's worth there's a working example of a cluster using static discovery in the broker's `examples/features/clustered/clustered-static-discovery` directory. In fact, there's lots of examples of different cluster configurations shipped with the broker. You can run the examples, modify them, run them again, etc. to get a better idea of how everything works.

Comment: Very helpful, I've gone through your suggestions and updated my configuration and I'm no longer getting the null exceptions, but I am still getting "unable to authorize cluster control". Updated configs are here: https://gist.github.com/atrauzzi/a5165f19c4813598627bfdfde05a4f0d

Comment: Is it common for a bit of connectivity errors like this prior to both workers in a cluster being up and ready?

Comment: No, it's not common. I'm looking through your config now. Looks like there still something misconfigured.

Comment: The connectors you've configured look incorrect. On both brokers both connectors are using the same IP address. I would expect for each broker to have connectors for both the `global` and `regional` brokers. Also, one of the connectors is using port `61617` but you don't have any acceptors listening on the port. I updated my answer with a few more (potential) issues.

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies.  I should have added, I'm using docker to port map on the same host.

Comment: I don't really understand what that means specifically for your environment.

Comment: Imagine all brokers are running on the same machine, basically.  Except with docker, I'm able to map ports so that they don't conflict.  For the sake of this discussion, I'm no longer mapping ports, just in case for some reason AMQ-A tries to connect to itself.

Comment: At this point it might be worth simplifying the environment by eliminating docker. Once you get it working without docker then you can add docker back into the mix. It's hard, if not impossible, to provide connection configuration recommendations without knowing exactly where those connections are going.

Comment: I believe I have it working now.  Am able to connect to one broker and receive messages sent to the other.  Thank you for your help! :)